# Printing --help text on GNU/Linux with the standard format

Tags: c, gnu

On GNU/Linux terminal, when I add `--help` to commands from GNU packages, I get a help text that is formatted in a very consistent way. These help texts list the options accepted by that command with this format:

> option characters, long options ............ [aligned] explanation of the option

For example, this is a part of the help text of the `man` command:

```
Usage: man [OPTION...] [SECTION] PAGE...

  -C, --config-file=FILE     use this user configuration file
  -d, --debug                emit debugging messages
  -D, --default              reset all options to their default values
      --warnings[=WARNINGS]  enable warnings from groff

 Main modes of operation:
  -f, --whatis               equivalent to whatis
  -k, --apropos              equivalent to apropos
  -K, --global-apropos       search for text in all pages
  -l, --local-file           interpret PAGE argument(s) as local filename(s)
  -w, --where, --path, --location
                             print physical location of man page(s)
  -W, --where-cat, --location-cat
                             print physical location of cat file(s)
```

I was wondering if there was a standard way (possibly used by GNU packages) to print with the same format, without having to deal with tab stops etc. I have found `getopt` from POSIX API to parse these options, but I can't find a way to print a list of them.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you. If you could post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Well, my pedantic side tells me I have to address issues  `On GNU/Linux terminal, when I add --help to any command` Terminal is unrelated to what a command excepts. And terminal code license and OS is unrelated to what command does with its arguments. And no, not all commands print help when passed `--help`. And no, not all commands output a "consistent" `--help` page... And asking for software recommendations is offtopic for stackoverflow. And, anyway, see man sources, which uses [argp](https://github.com/giraldeau/man-db-2.6.3/blob/d0b56430754b4908ec906a7cd3a7fce30825367d/src/mandb.c#L104)

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not sure this counts as a software recommendation. It's basically like asking what function Windows applications use for some specific functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU tools use *argp*, which is part of the GNU C library. It offers more options than `getopt`, including help.

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html